# What causes a person to remain in this world as a ghost?

Tags: midrash, death, tractate-brachot, soul, literalism

A *baraita* on [Berakhot 18b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.18b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) relates a story where a pious man sleeps in a cemetery and hears two spirits talking.  One of them suggests they wander the world, and the other says she can't because she was buried in a reed mat (rather than a shroud).  So these are spirits of people who once lived.  This happens three years in a row, so it's not that the spirits are (for some reason) held there for the first year after death.

From what I understand of our tradition, it is not normal for spirits of the dead to hang around on earth.  Why is it, then, that some do (according to this *baraita*, anyway)?  Do spirits remain if there is some sort of unfinished business?  If so, what qualifies?

One might think that the one is kept here because of an improper burial, but the *other* spirit doesn't seem to have trouble roaming, and so I infer was buried properly.

Comment: FWIW this Braisa is originally found in Avos d’Rebbi Nassan ch. 3. Might help track down some different commentaries on the Braisa.

Comment: I think they are sentimentally attached to old places or items that were once their properties in former lifetimes. I also think they stay close to their children and living descendants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[R. Ezekiel Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Landau) discusses this aspect of the tale in his commentary there. He explains that the spirit cannot leave the body until the body decomposes, and that is why we conduct burials in a manner that will quicken the process, by burying directly in the ground and using linen shrouds. A mat of reeds *slows* the rotting process and therefore the body of the girl buried in the mat of reeds had not yet decomposed, and this prevented her spirit from leaving.

[Tzelach Berachot 18b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37718&st=&pgnum=37)

> הגם שכל דברי רז"ל באגדות יש בהן ענין נסתר וברמז ובחידה דיברו  מכל מקום גם פשטן של הדברים צריך שלא יהיו דברים זרים ויוצאים מהיקש הטבע  ולכאורה תשובה זו שקבורה במחצלת של קנים ומתוך כך אינה יכולה לשוט בעולם  הוא דבר זר מאוד  וכי הגוף עולה מקברו  הרי הגוף מוטל כאבן דומם בקברו  אבל הרוח הוא העולה  רוח הצדיק עולה למעלה בגבהי מרומים  ורוח הרשעים נתונה בכף הקלע  אבל הגוף בין של הצדיקים ובין של הרשעים נשאר בקבר  אך גוף של הצדיק מושכב במנוחה עד יגיע עת קץ אז יעמוד לגורלו לקץ הימין  וגוף של הרשע בשרו עליו יכאב וקשה רמה למת כמחט והנפש נידונית בכף הקלע  ומה ענין המחצלת להרוח שאינו דבר גשמי שיתעטף במחצלת של קנים  ועוד  ששוב לשנה אחרת חזרה ואמרה לה בואי ונשוט  והלא השיבה לה אשתקד שאינה יכולה  וכאשר השיבה לה באמת לא כך אמרתי לך וכו' ונראה על פי שאמרו במס' שבת דף קנ"ב ע"ב כל מה שאומרים בפני המת וכו'  וחד אמר עד שיתעכל הבשר דכתיב אך בשרו עליו יכאב ונפשו עליו תאבל  הרי שכל זמן שבשר הגוף קיים אין הנפש יכולה להפרד ממנו עד שיכלה בשר הגוף לגמרי ואז עולה הרוח למעלה  ולכך המצוה לקבור בקרקע כמבואר בסנהדרין דף מ"ו כדי שירקב הגוף מהרה  ולכך התכריכין הם של פשתן הכלים ונרקבים מהרה שלא יעכבו רקיבת הגוף  וזו שנקברה במחצלת של קנים שהיתה אמה עניה ולא היה סיפוק בידה להלבישה תכריכין של בגדי פשתן  וקברה אותה בעיטוף מחצלת של קנים  וזהו אינו מתרקב כל כך בנקל  נשאר גם הגוף קיים בבשרו ולא היתה יכולה להפרד ולעלות למעלה  ואמנם בשנה השניה היתה השניה סבורה שכבר במשך שנה שעברה נרקב המחצלת עם הבשר ותהא יכולה לעלות  לכן אמרה לה בואי ונשוט  וזהו השיבה לה שעדיין לא נרקבה המחצלת ולכן גם הבשר לא נרקב ואינה יכולה לעלות

Comment: Thank you (and +1), but what about the one who was ready to wander, so (by implication) wasn't buried in a reed mat?  It chose to stay around as a spirit even though it could have left?

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's why she was able to leave.

Comment: Was able to, but didn't.  Does that mean that ghosts stay with their bodies until they decide to leave (and can)? There's no automatic "advancement", so to speak?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Why assume she didn't? It just says that she asked the other girl to go exploring with her. It doesn't say that she hadn't ever left her body yet.

Comment: @Alex sorry I was unclear.  I have some possibly-incorrect understandings: that soul = spirit, that the soul is supposed to ascend from this world (after up to a year, during which we say *kaddish*), and that this process is automatic.  Here, though, we have a spirit that stayed in the world -- or, at least, was present in the cemetery -- for more than two years.  I'm wondering why that one was still here at all when it sounds like she was able to leave.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I wasn’t challenging your understanding of souls/spirits etc. I was just saying that the Talmudic passage doesn’t say that the other girl had remained behind as well; it’s possible she moved on right when her body decomposed and was simply inviting her friend for a night out.

Comment: Mossad HaRav Kook published a commentary which states that since her family was too poor to afford proper linen shrouds she was ashamed to be seen in such attire (insinuating that the disembodied spirit appears dressed in the same clothing as the body itself).

Comment: So a spirit cannot leave the body, unless a body decomposes? What happens to the soul, if the body is preserved in ice or chemicals, let's say for hundreds of years?

Comment: @RitaGeraghty You may want to ask that as a standalone question.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex had a very good answer.  Just thought I should add that Maharasha explains that the lowest part of the soul (Nefesh) remains with the body after death and the most elevated part of the soul (Neshama) separates from the body after death and ascends to higher realms.  His commentary (see the footnote in ArtScroll) says that the Germara here speaks of a Rooakh, which is part of the soul that is intermediate between the Nefesh and Neshama and which sometimes remains with the dead body and sometimes roams free and ascends to higher realms where the Neshama is.

Interestingly, Maharasha expressed disbelief that R' Yehuda bar Il'ai would spend the night of Rosh Hashanah in a cemetery and thus proposed that this entire story reflects what occurred in dreams.